# Laravel MongoDB OR statement

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am experiencing a problem with results with OR statements. I am using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb found at https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Example, queries $a and $b separately work good.

```
$a = Conversation::where('sender_participant', '=', Auth::user()->id);
$b = Conversation::where('recipient_participant', '=', Auth::user()->id);

$a->count(); //returns 4 (correct as per data in database)
$b->count(); //returns 2 (correct as per data in database)
```

However, when I combine queries $a and $b like;

```
$c = Conversation::where('sender_participant', '=', Auth::user()->id)
               ->orWhere('recipient_participant', '=', Auth::user()->id);

$c->count(); //(wrong) returns 0 instead of 6.
```

I'm I doing anything wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you pasted your code wrong. Shouldn't there be a difference between the first and the second condition?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for noting.

Comment: No problem. It's probably also useful if you make a note about the package you are using for MongoDB support...

Comment: Could it be that `count()` is somehow broken? what if you try `->get()` and then count the result? (Just guessing)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.